# How do I link .NET libraries into IronScheme?

Tags: clr, ironscheme

I have been messing around with IronScheme and I am intrigued by it. I saw [this post](http://ironscheme.codeplex.com/discussions/63157) on creating WinForms in IronScheme, but any time I try to do reference a DLL like this:

```
(clr-reference System)
(clr-reference System.Data)
(clr-reference System.Windows.Forms)
etc...
```

I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception durring evaluation:
&who: "clr-reference"
&message: "Assembly not found"
&syntax:
  form: ( <the assembly> )
  subform: #f
```

I call `(import (rnrs) (ironscheme clr))` to begin with. Is there something else I have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug that recently crept in :(

It has been fixed in the RC5  release.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Cheers

leppie